# How to wrap code in a function correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have a code that automatically creates a table for me. It gathers information from a saved file, however, I have two of these files and currently can call one at the time. How can I possibly wrap this code in a function so that there are two calls on the same code with different information that will be put in it? So right now I am using getElementById on file "house-data" but I also want to have this same js on a file "senate-data"

I thought of creating some sort of if statement where if(you have one file): do this
else 
do that. But this method doesnt work.

```
var table = "";
var cols = 1;
var members = data.results[0].members;
var rows = members.length;
table += "<tr>" +
    "<th>" + "Full Name" + "</th>" +
    "<th>" + "Party" + "</th>" +
    "<th>" + "State" + "</th>" +
    "<th>" + "Seniority"+ "</th>" +
    "<th>" + "Total Votes"+ "</th>" + "</tr>";

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        table +=
            "<td>" + members[r].first_name +", "+
            (members[r].middle_name || " ") +" "+
            members[r].last_name + "</td>";

        table += "<td>" + members[r].party + "</td>" + "<td>" + members[r].state + "</td>" + "<td>" + members[r].seniority + "</td>";
        if (members[r].votes_with_party_pct === undefined) {
            table += "<td>" + "-" + "</td>"
        } else {   
            table += "<td>" + members[r].votes_with_party_pct + "%" + "</td>"
        }
    }
    table += "<tr>";
}

  document.getElementById("house-data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(table);
```

Comment: `function xy(elementId, data) { [...] document.getElementById(elementId)[...] }`?

Comment: why do you convert *html* markup into *json*, before adding it to the *DOM*?

Answer (score 0):

```
function tableCreator(elementID, data) { 

    [...] 
    document.getElementById(elementID)[...] 

}
```

above will work for you and keep in mind to check

```
var members = data.results[0].members;
```

is available before going to `for` loop